# A comprehensive overview of finite fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, nt.number-theory, finite-fields

I've read numerous *introductions* to finite fields, but I feel like my intuition about them is fairly lacking.  Considering that finite fields are the the most "inert" objects in algebraic geometry, I think I could use a serious surge of perspective.

What I would like to read now is a comprehensive overview that tells me "everything I need to know" about how finite fields and their algebraic closures work, algebraically.  I don't mind working out the proofs on my own if they are terse or absent; I'm just looking for quality and quantity of results.  Hopefully some intense reading will help steep out some of my insecurities about characteristic p.

Can anyone recommend a single source for such an overview?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are a geometer over finite fields, then the Frobenius will make sure that you are almost as good as in the algebraically closed case. Befriend the Frobenius, and then you are in a safe position.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Finite Fields](http://books.google.com/books?id=xqMqxQTFUkMC) by R. Lidl and H Niederreiter (CUP). Probably as comprehensive as it gets.
The ams review calls it the ``the Bible of finite fields''. You can find it (the review)[here](http://www.ams.org/bull/1999-36-01/S0273-0979-99-00768-5/S0273-0979-99-00768-5.pdf).

Comment: Your link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

The really important things in algebraic number theory start from group cohomology and theorems like Hilbert 90, but you'll be better searching/asking for different keywords than `finite fields` then.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a single comprehensive source (just edited the question to reflect this).